# Strange issue with stereo triangulation: TWO valid solutions

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, triangulation, pose-estimation

I am currently using OpenCV for a pose estimation related work, in which I am triangulating points between pairs for reconstruction and scale factor estimation. I have encountered a strange issue while working on this, especially in the opencv functions recoverPose() and triangulatePoints().

Say I have camera 1 and camera 2, spaced apart in X, with cam1 at (0,0,0) and cam2 to the right of it (positive X). I have two arrays points1 and points2 that are the matched features between the two images. According to the OpenCV documentation and code, I have noted two points:

1. recoverPose() assumes that points1 belong to the camera at (0,0,0).
2. triangulatePoints() is called twice: one from recoverPose() to tell us which of the four R/t combinations is valid, and then again from my code, and the documentation says:

   ```
   cv::triangulatePoints(P1, P2, points1, points2, points3D)  : points1 -> P1 and points2 -> P2.
   ```

Hence, as in the case of recoverPose(), it is safe to assume that P1 is [I|0] and P2 is [R|t].

What I actually found: It doesn't work that way. Although my camera1 is at 0,0,0 and camera2 is at 1,0,0 (1 being up to scale), the only correct configuration is obtained if I run

```
recoverPose(E, points2, points1...)
triangulatePoints([I|0], [R|t], points2, points1, pts3D)
```

which should be incorrect, because points2 is the set from R|t, not points1. I tested an image pair of a scene in my room where there are three noticeable objects after triangulation: a monitor and two posters on the wall behind it. Here are the point clouds resulting from the triangulation (excuse the MS Paint)

If I do it the OpenCV's prescribed way: (poster points dispersed in space, weird looking result)

[image: Wrong]

If I do it my (wrong?) way:

[image: Correct]

Can anybody share their views about what's going on here? Technically, both solutions are valid because all points fall in front of both cameras: and I didn't know what to pick until I rendered it as a pointcloud. Am I doing something wrong, or is it an error in the documentation? I am not that knowledgeable about the theory of computer vision so it might be possible I am missing something fundamental here. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? What version (exactly) of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: Honestly, no. I just went with the method that gave the right results. I am using 2.4.11 in C++.

Comment: How did you track the matched features in 2nd frame? Did you use `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` ? I got lost about your feature detection and tracking part in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue. I believe OpenCV defines the translation vector in the opposite way that one would expect. With your camera configuration the translation vector would be [-1, 0, 0]. It's counter intuitive, but both RecoverPose and stereoCalibrate give this translation vector.

I found that when I used the incorrect but intuitive translation vector (eg. [1, 0, 0]) I couldn't get correct results unless I swapped points1 and points2, just as you did.

I suspect the translation vector actually translate the points into the other camera coordinate system, not the vector to translate the camera poses. The [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#details), seems to imply that this is the case:

> The joint rotation-translation matrix [R|t] is called a matrix of extrinsic parameters. It is used to describe the camera motion around a static scene, or vice versa, rigid motion of an object in front of a still camera. That is, [R|t] translates coordinates of a **point (X,Y,Z) to a coordinate system**, fixed with respect to the camera.

Wikipedia has a nice description on [Translation of Axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_of_axes):

> In the new coordinate system, the point P will appear to have been translated in the opposite direction. For example, if the xy-system is translated a distance h to the right and a distance k upward, then P will appear to have been translated a distance h to the left and a distance k downward in the x'y'-system

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this observation is discussed in this thread
[Is the recoverPose() function in OpenCV is left-handed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810218/is-the-recoverpose-function-in-opencv-is-left-handed)

Translation t is the vector from cam2 to cam1 in cam2 frame.

Comment: Then the rotation R should also be inverted?